# how to find nearest latitude and longitude form current place?

Tags: ios, math, ios6, core-location

I have a dictionary with a collection of n number of latitude, longitude and address. I want to  calculate which (latitude and langitude)point is closest from current user location(latitude ,langitude) in ios?

Thanks in advance

Comment: "i calculate which point is closest from current point in ios?" - I don't know if you calculate it. I have no knowledge of what you are doing currently.

Comment: want to calculate based on co-ordinates ...?

Comment: yes i want calculate based on coordinate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to calculate based on the  co-ordinates , here is simple scenario :
  Just take all of the `"CLLocationCoordinate2D"` from your dictionary .

For ex:

```
MKPointAnnotation *annotaion=[MKPointAnnotaion alloc]alloc];

CLLocationCoordinate2D pointACoordinate = [annotation coordinate];
//  If you have the co-ordinates in hand , then just make " CLLocation *loc2; " using Co-ordinates  

loc2 = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:pointACoordinate.latitude longitude:pointACoordinate.longitude];
```

then put loop or whichever  you want to calculate the less distance by comparing with all using this

```
CLLocationDistance nearLocation=[ location distanceFromLocation:loc2]; // location --> your current Location
```

If you want to achieve other than it : Then just follow  `saury answer`, they are good to achieve perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

This problem is similar to finding the K Nearest Neighbor (KNN) problem.
I will suggest you to go through following links to have an understanding on how to solve your problem

1. [KNN Wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-nearest_neighbors_algorithm)
2. Good [blog](http://saravananthirumuruganathan.wordpress.com/2010/05/17/a-detailed-introduction-to-k-nearest-neighbor-knn-algorithm/) having detailed overview