# get nearest locations from my current location

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad, geocoding, clgeocoder

I am currently developing a mobile application for iOS which consists a part that requires to determine the users current location and from current location, i want to find nearest locations.

Is there any way to implement this ??

I have done some coding for finding current location of user.
here is my code snippet,

```
CLGeocoder *geocoder = [[CLGeocoder alloc] init];
    [geocoder reverseGeocodeLocation:locationManager.location
                   completionHandler:^(NSArray *placemarks, NSError *error) {
                       NSLog(@"reverseGeocodeLocation:completionHandler: Completion Handler called!");

                       if (error){
                           NSLog(@"Geocode failed with error: %@", error);
                           return;

                       }

                       CLPlacemark *placemark = [placemarks objectAtIndex:0];
                       NSLog(@"placemarks=%@",[placemarks objectAtIndex:0]);
```

But my problem is, how will i get nearest other locations ?? from my current location which i already fetched.

**Thanks in advance.**

Comment: go to [this Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17085668/how-to-find-nearest-latitude-and-longitude-form-current-place), this has similar question. I guess this will help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
MKPointAnnotation *ann=[MKPointAnnotaion alloc] init];
CLLocationCoordinate2D point = [ann coordinate];
myLocation = [[CLLocation alloc] initWithLatitude:point.latitude longitude:point.longitude];
CLLocationDistance nearByLocation=[yourCurrentLocation distanceFromLocation:myLocation];
```

Comment: How to intialize myLocation ? and what to put in place of `yourCurrentLocation` ? i have wrote my code snippet above for current location.

Comment: check this [tutorial](http://mobileorchard.com/hello-there-a-corelocation-tutorial/) for get current location

Comment: dude i am getting current location but what to write in place of `yourCurrentLocation` ??? i wrote `locationManager.location` in place of `yourCurrentLocation` is it right ?

Comment: lol, i am asking because i dont have real device now, i am testing it in simulator.

Comment: `CLLocationDistance nearByLocation=[locationManager.location distanceFromLocation:myLocation];                                           NSLog(@"nearByLocation=%f",nearByLocation);` myLog shows some points like `8230614.551295` what are they ?